# Octave doesn't disp my values, and only stores in ans variable

Tags: function, octave

```
function t = metodoDeNewton(a, t0, N, epsilon)
  a = 2;
  epsilon = 1e-10;
  t0 = 1;
  N = 20;
  t = zeros(1, N+1);
  t(1) = t0;
  for i = 1:N
    t(i+1) = t(i) - (t(i)^2 - (a - sin(t(i)))) / (2 * t(i) - cos(t(i)));
    if (abs(t(i+1) - t(i)) < epsilon)
    break;
  endif
endfor
endfunction

t = metodoDeNewton(a, t0, N, epsilon);

% Mostra a última iteração, que é a aproximação da raiz da equação
disp(t(end));

% Estima a ordem de convergência e o coeficiente assintótico de convergência
% Para isso, calcula a razão entre duas iterações consecutivas e a razão entre
% o erro absoluto dessas iterações e o erro absoluto das iterações anteriores
r = zeros(1, length(t) - 1);
k = zeros(1, length(t) - 1);
for i = 2:length(t)
  r(i-1) = t(i) / t(i-1);
  k(i-1) = abs(t(i) - t(i-1)) / abs(t(i-1) - t(i-2));
endfor

% Mostra a razão e o coeficiente assintótico de convergência
x = disp(r(end))
y = disp(k(end))
```

The code doesn't display my final values, and it doesn't store any of the variables I define either (like the r and k variables), the only variable it stores is the ans, and I don't really understand where it's that's coming from.

Comment: I suspect that when you hit run it is not running the stuff under `endfunction` as you are expecting, but it's running the function `metodoDeNewton` with no inputs. It doesn't require any inputs because you define them all at the top anyway (this makes your function definition with inputs pointless), then the only output is `t`, but as you've not said `t = metodoDeNewton()` it is output as `ans` instead. You should put local functions at the _bottom_ of scripts, and remove the overriding of your function's inputs. Read how to [debug](https://docs.octave.org/v5.2.0/Debugging.html) your code

Comment: Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Comment: @Wolfie In MATLAB functions go at the bottom of the script, in Octave they need to be defined above where they’re used.

Comment: @Cris Ah, hopefully some of the other stuff in my comment is relevant, I also removed the MATLAB tag for exactly this reason :)

Comment: @wolfie Yes, your comment was spot on except for the one detail. One of the many reasons MATLAB and Octave tags need to be used correctly.